# No optimal screen resolution for external screen

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors, xorg, display-resolution

I am trying to attach an external monitor (Samsung LC34H890WJI) to the laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 (Samsung NP940Z5L); however, I cannot achieve a stable maximum resolution for the monitor, which should be 3440 x 1440.

When I am in the user selection menu, the monitor actually has a resolution of 3440 x 1440. But when I log in, I get resolution 1280 x 800, although occasionally 1680 x 1050 or 2560 x 1080 is available (which could disappear again after, e.g., laptop sleep).

My graphics are GeForce GTX 950M/PCIe/SSE2 with Nvidia driver version 455.28. I tried reinstalling Nvidia drivers, but it did not work.

I had the same problem before upgrading Ubuntu 18.04, although I did not really try to resolve it.

UPD: It seems it is really a problem with Nvidia drivers. When I run Ubuntu on Wayland, it chooses Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2) as graphics, and all desired resolutions appear. On the other hand, when I try to run nvidia-xconfig, I obtain the following message:

```
WARNING: Unable to locate/open X configuration file.

New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'
```

After reboot, the laptop hangs on. Removing xorg.conf and xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original resolves the problem.

So, the question is, how to fix Nvidia drivers.

UPD2:

I tried looking at journalctl -b-1 output for freezing boot with xorg.conf, and I noticed the following lines:

```
ноя 09 01:29:04 aremizova-940Z5L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1129]: dbus-daemon[1129]: [session uid=121 pid=1129] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.portal.IBus' requested by ':1.33' (uid=121 pid=1446 comm="ibus-daemon --panel disable -r --xim " label="unconfined")
ноя 09 01:29:04 aremizova-940Z5L org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1460]: The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
ноя 09 01:29:04 aremizova-940Z5L org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1460]: > Warning:          Unsupported maximum keycode 569, clipping.
ноя 09 01:29:04 aremizova-940Z5L org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1460]: >                   X11 cannot support keycodes above 255.
ноя 09 01:29:04 aremizova-940Z5L org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1460]: > Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym Invalid
ноя 09 01:29:04 aremizova-940Z5L org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1460]: Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
```

They do not appear in the log for boot without xorg.conf.

UPD 3: Switching NVIDIA X Server - PRIME Profiles to Intel does not help, so probably it is a Xorg issue rather than drivers, but I am not sure.

Comment: Could it be a hardware issue with a substandard HDMI cable? I would try a short, good quality HDMI connection and then look what it says at supported in the menu.

Comment: @emk2203 I think not, see edit

Comment: Interesting. Really weird that the driver sometimes detects certain resolutions and sometimes not.  Maybe look at the generated `xorg.conf` file and only comment out what might cause the hang?